# Почему при перестановки условий с операцией and, код некорректен

Tags: python

Простите возможно глупый вопрос, но почему если поменять условие p < len(a) и a[p] >= x местами то код будет выдавать ошибку. Ведь посути же от перестановки ничего поменяется

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
x = int(input())
p = 0
while p < len(a) and a[p] >= x:
    p += 1
print(p + 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

От перестановки меняется порядок выполнения.

1. Случай `while p < len(a) and a[p] >= x:`
   На последней итерации `p` равно длине массива, поэтому условие  `p < len(a)` не выполняется и цикл прекращается сразу. Условие `a[p] >= x` **не проверяется!**, потому что незачем, т.к. первое условие уже не выполнено *(это называется "[вычисления по короткой схеме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5)")*.
2. Случай `while a[p] >= x and p < len(a):` На последней итерации `p` равно длине массива, поэтому попытка обратиться к `a[p]` вызывает исключение `IndexError`, т.к. такого элемента нет, ведь у самого последнего элемента индекс `p-1` (т.е. `len(a)-1`)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy о, спасибо. Добавил.